# WordPress update_post_meta is returning odd results

Tags: wordpress

Problems with WordPress update_post_meta.

I have a function that should be updating _gravity_form_data.  It works, but it is adding extra data for some reason.  Here's the function:

Here is the function:

```
function wpufe_gravity_custom_video( $post_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['custom_video'])) {

        $custom_video = 'a:13:{s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:2:"no";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:3:"yes";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:2:"no";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:2:"no";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";}';

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gravity_form_data', $custom_video );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'wpufe_gravity_custom_video' );
add_action( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update', 'wpufe_gravity_custom_video' );
```

It SHOULD be making _gravity_form_data have this content:

```
a:13:{s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:2:"no";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:3:"yes";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:2:"no";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:2:"no";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";}
```

Yet when it updates the _gravity_form_data field, its output is:

```
s:429:"a:13:{s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:2:"no";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:3:"yes";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:2:"no";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:2:"no";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";}";
```

Why is it adding the s:429:" in the beginning and then the extra "; at the end?  And most importantly, how do I fix it? :)

Thanks so much!

---

UPDATE:  Was suggested to serialize the data, so I did:

```
function wpufe_gravity_custom_video( $post_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['custom_video'])) {
        $gubcustom_video = array('id' => 2, 'display_title' => '', 'display_description' => '', 'disable_woocommerce_price' => 'no', 'price_before' => '', 'price_after' => '', 'disable_calculations' => 'yes', 'disable_label_subtotal' => 'no', 'disable_label_option' => 'no', 'disable_label_total' => 'no', 'label_subtotal' => 'Subtotal', 'label_options' => 'Options', 'label_total' => 'Total');
        $gubvideodata = serialize($gubcustom_video);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gravity_form_data', $gubvideodata );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'wpufe_gravity_custom_video' );
add_action( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update', 'wpufe_gravity_custom_video' );
```

...and still get the incorrect data posted to mysql.

Is there a way to just insert that string I need to insert?  That's all I want to do, is update the database with that text.

I can do this in phpMySql easily, just copy and paste the text and it works like a champ.  That's the solution I'm hoping for.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  WP User Frontend Pro was setting the meta key with its own value of "1", causing it to re-serialize the serialized string.  Problem solved by removing the WPUF meta key and just leaving the field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a serialized array that you are trying to insert manually but you should insert it by serializing it using `serialize` function, for example:

```
$custom_video = array('id' => 2, 'display_title' => '');
$data = serialize($custom_video);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gravity_form_data', $data );
```

Also, try using following hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_data' );

function save_meta_data($post_id)
{
    $custom_video = array('id' => 2, 'display_title' => '');
    $data = serialize($custom_video);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_gravity_form_data', $data );
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with some edits, if you could have a look I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I'm looking for a way to just enter the raw data rather than messing with serializing it.  I can just paste it in via myPhpAdmin, but need an automated solution. ;-)  Why cant I just insert it as plain text?  Thanks!